# Efficient way of downloading data in Android App from MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, download

I was just wondering if my code is ok in terms of downloading. My app needs a lot of data from a database so quick download times are crucial. The download time is ok but I think it can be programmed more efficient. Can you have a look at this? This class downloads many different companies and when downloaded they are put in a HashMap corresponding to their category. When finished downloading this class return a HashMap which contains multiple Hashmaps(categories) and in these Hashmaps the downloaded data. Dont mind the actual workflow but please concentrate on the way this class downloads data. Is there a way to do this faster?

```
public class CompanyDAO {

    private static Controller delegate;
    private static String companyUrl = "http:// URL HERE";

    private Map<Object, Object> companyMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    private Map<String, Integer> pinMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    public CompanyDAO (Controller _delegate, Map<String, Integer> map) {
        delegate = _delegate; //reference to controller
        pinMap = map;

    }

    public void getCompanyData(ArrayList<Object> categoriesArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> categoriesInMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //ArrayList<Object> categoriesInMapArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
            companyMap.put(categoriesArray.get(i), categoriesInMap);
        }
        this.downloadCompanyData();
    }

    private void downloadCompanyData() {

        companyUrl = companyUrl + delegate.ID;
       try {
           new DownloadCompanyData().execute(companyUrl).get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TimeoutException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

   private class DownloadCompanyData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
           String response = "";
           for (String url : urls) {
               DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
               try {
                   HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                   InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                   BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                   String s = "";
                   while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                       response += s;
                   }

               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           return response;
       }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



           JSONArray companyDataArray;

           try {
               companyDataArray = new JSONArray(result);

               for(int i=0;i<companyDataArray.length();i++){
                   JSONObject id = companyDataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   String catName = id.getString(Controller.CAT_NAME);

                   if (companyMap.get(catName) != null) {
                       Markers marker = new Markers(new LatLng(id.getDouble("latitude"), id.getDouble("longitude")), id.getString(Controller.CAT_NAME), id.getString(Controller.ID), id.getString(Controller.SUBSCRIPTION), pinMap.get(catName), id.getString(Controller.TITLE), id.getString(Controller.COMPANY_NAME), id.getString(Controller.WWW), id.getString(Controller.STREET), id.getString(Controller.HOUSE_NUMBER), id.getString(Controller.HOUSE_ADD));

                       ((Map<String,Object>) companyMap.get(catName)).put(id.getString(Controller.TITLE), marker.markerInformationMap);

                   }

               }
               delegate.setCompanyHashMap(companyMap);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using HTTP to connect to a remote DB? This is superfluous overhead.

Comment: Whats a good alternative then?

Comment: Why not connect directly to MySQL server?

Comment: Thats not safe enough. Having a PHP middle layer serves as a gatekeeper for me

Comment: Well, that's definitely slower, and your question was *Is there a way to do this faster?*. So faster is not using the PHP layer. And what kind of safety does this give you, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're missing the point of the `AsyncTask`

it's supposed to do all the work in `doInBackground()` and then use the `onPostExecute` to deliver it to the UI.

But what you're doing is doing the network operation on `doInBackground` and doing data parsing on `onPostExecute`.

Furthermore, a JSON object is a raw data that needs further parsing. You should do all the parsing on the background. For example, let's say your companyData is address, phone number, size and name. You could have a class like this (p.s. I'm writing all this without testing, there will be a little mistake here in there, but you'll get the idea):

```
 public class CompanyData{
     private String name, address, phone;
     private int size;
     public CompanyData(JsonObject jo){
         name = jo.getString("name");
         address = jo.getString("address");
         phone = jo.getString("phone");
         size = jo.getInt("size");
     }
     // put a bunch of get methods here...
     // getName(), getAddress(), etc.
 }
```

then on your 'protected Map doInBackground(String... urls) ' you complete the network operation, create the JsonArray, create a `Map<String,CompanyData>`, loop through the array creating CompanyData objects and placing them into the Map and return the map to your `protected void onPostExecute(Map<String,CompanyData> result)` and inside the post execute it's just pass this result to the UI.

happy coding.

Comment: thanks for the comment! Im going look in to this now and let you know if everything worked! :-)

Comment: Everything is working fine. Although I dont directly see any speed difference I get your point of doing all this work in the background.

So I implemented the json parsing in the doInBackground like you suggested.


But the download progress is fine then? The app works fine btw but I just thought that there were improvements in the downloading and parsing phase.

Comment: depending on what platform you're targeting you can change to `HttpURLConnection` instead of `HttpClient`, as I've heard is more efficient, but you have to Google for details on it. The whole `stream->String->Json` part is that the way of doing and I've never seen a better way. The main idea on what I suggested is that you completely off-load the UI, so even if it takes the same time, this time will be taken on a background thread and your UI will keep running fast and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I always doing something like this..

```
...
private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CompanyList;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray Company = null;
static String url_all_company = "http://your_site/files.php";
....

private class CompanyData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Load data..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        CompanyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Building Parameters if any.. to fetching all data, don't declare any param
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_company, "POST", param);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Company: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // Company found
                // Getting Array of Company
                Company = json.getJSONArray(TAG_COMPANIES);

                // looping through All Company
                for (int i = 0; i < Company.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = Company.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = json.getString(TAG_GID);
                    String name = json.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String jml = json.getString(TAG_EMPLOYEE);
                    String deskripsi = json.getString(TAG_DESKRIPSI);
                    String logo = json.getString(TAG_LOGO);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_GID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_EMPLOYEE, jml);
                    map.put(TAG_DESKRIPSI, deskripsi);
                    map.put(TAG_LOGO, logo);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    CompanyList.add(map);

                }
            } else {
                // no CompanyList found

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;    

    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
         list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

         // Getting adapter by passing data ArrayList
         adapter=new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, CompanyList);        
         list.setAdapter(adapter);

         pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```